# Get correct length for unicode characters

Tags: neovim, functions

Basically title, the length of unicode characters as calculated by the `len()` function is off by one, for example

```
:echo len("à")
2
```

or

```
:echo len("°")
2
```

is there a way to fix this, maybe by setting some options?

Comment: There’s lots of resources that discuss the complications of counting length of unicode strings, but I can’t find one. It matters how you count: bytes? “Characters”? But some characters are combining and you don’t see them as you might think... etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny, I'm used to using [`len()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#len()) to count items in a list but it turns out it's valid to pass a string, too, in which case the function returns length in bytes. I would use [`strlen()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#strlen()) for that but either one works per documentation for `len()`:

> When `{expr}` is a String or a Number the length in bytes is used, as with `strlen()`.

Anyways, it sounds like you want to count characters instead. `strlen()` has a sibling named [`strchars()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#strchars()) that does just that. Using your example string...

```
:echo strchars("°")
```

...displays "1". That solves the "off by one" result you described, I think.

Related to DBK's observations in his comment, the function also takes an optional second parameter (*Vim version >= 7.4.755*) that dictates whether composing characters are counted or not. Quoting [the function's docs](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#strchars()), when `{skipcc}` is...

- ...omitted or zero, composing characters are counted separately.
- ...set to 1, Composing characters are ignored.

Not sure whether that part is relevant to you or not.